# How to trigger editchanged event of textbox on button click in swift4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am aware of editchanged event of a textbox and it is working properly when I change the text in textbox using mac's keypad but I have made numeric buttons and when I change text using buttons the editchanged of textbox is not triggered.

This is my button event

```
@IBAction func digitbuttonpress(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if(text1.isFirstResponder)
    {
        text1.text = text1.text! + sender.titleLabel!.text!
    }
    else if(text2.isFirstResponder)
    {
        text2.text = text2.text! + sender.titleLabel!.text!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the code inside editingChanged in a function say `sharedTrigger` and call it from anywhere

```
@IBAction func digitbuttonpress(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if(text1.isFirstResponder)
    {
        text1.text = text1.text! + sender.titleLabel!.text!
    }
    else if(text2.isFirstResponder)
    {
        text2.text = text2.text! + sender.titleLabel!.text!
    }

    self.sharedTrigger()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot programmatically trigger the `editChanged` event, that event happens when user edits the `textField` (not textBox).

Whatever you want to do after the event, you will have to call it programmatically from `digitbuttonpress`:

```
@IBAction func digitbuttonpress(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if text1.isFirstResponder {
        text1.text = text1.text! + sender.titleLabel!.text!
        // explicitly call the handler
        self.text1EditChangedHandler()
    } else if text2.isFirstResponder {
        text2.text = text2.text! + sender.titleLabel!.text!
        // explicitly call the handler
        self.text2EditChangedHandler()
    }
}
```

Comment: actually it turn that you can trigger the **editChanged** event programmatically 

`textField.sendActions(for: .editingChanged)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a new function - you can call your existing edit changed function from code:

```
@IBAction func digitbuttonpress(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if(text1.isFirstResponder)
    {
        text1.text = text1.text! + sender.titleLabel!.text!
        editChanged(text1)
    }
    else if(text2.isFirstResponder)
    {
        text2.text = text2.text! + sender.titleLabel!.text!
        editChanged(text2)
    }
}

@IBAction func editChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Text Changed", sender)
    // do whatever else you want to do here
}
```